# Are underscores allowed in numeric literals in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, numbers

Can you use underscores in numbers in Java?  I saw this code in a blog, and it works, but will it continue to work in the future? Is it a feature or a bug?

```
long oneBillion = 1_000_000_000L;
```

Comment: Not allowed till JAVA 6....

Comment: @Braj No, [added in Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) (not 6).

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, you are correct, Thanks for correcting...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a feature, new in Java 7. You can rely on it remaining.  There are some restrictions, though; see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html).

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 supports the feature of having underscores in the numeric literals to improve the readability of the values being assigned.

but the underscore usage is restricted to be in between two numeric digits, i.e not at the beginning or ending of the numeric values but should be confined between two digits, should not be as a prefix to l,f used to represent long and float values and not in between radix prefixes also.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

> Can you use underscores in numbers in Java?

Yes.

Use in numeric literals: int, long, float,  double, and more to group digits as you desire.

Works with binary, decimal, octal, and hex notation.

> will it continue to work in the future?

Yes.

Works in Java 7, Java 8, Java 9, and later.

> Is it a feature or a bug?

Feature.

## Details

Yes, you are using a [feature added](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) in Java 7, and continued in Java 8 and Java 9.

You can use an underscore between digits. You can even use a group of multiple underscores between digits, if you so desire. You can use them on whole numbers (integers) and on fractional numbers ( float, double ). In a fractional number, you can use them on either or both sides of the decimal point.

You can use them in hex (base 16), binary (base 2), and octal (base 8) numbers as well as base 10 numbers.

You may group any number of digits as you see fit.

The purpose is strictly *readability by humans*. Java sees no meaning in the underscores. The presence or absence of the underscores in a numeric literal has *no* effect on your code.

Read [this half-page of documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) to see some helpful examples of right and wrong usages.